# Bootstrap modal not showing on dynamic loop of <li> tag's 'button' click, How to do it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ejs

I have buttons in 'li' tag loop, on that info button's click I want to open particular modals.
here is the code and image for your information : [using EJS]

EJS loop is working fine, after clicking that info button modal is opening but not showing the modal popop. I have checked generated modal code in inspect element but not showing in screen

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
  <% item.jobApplications.forEach((applicant)=>{ %>

    <li class="border border-dark">
      <!-- <a href="#infoModal<%= applicant._id %>" class="infobtn badge rounded-pill bg-info text-dark" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#infoModal<%= applicant._id %>">info</a> -->
      <button class="infobtn badge rounded-pill bg-info text-dark" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#infoModal<%= applicant._id %>">info</button>
      <span class="small-bold">Name:</span>
      <span class="small"><%=applicant.candidateName %></span>

      <span class="small-bold">Percentage:</span></td>
      <span class="small"><%=applicant.candidateDegreePercent %> %</span>

    </li>
    <!-- Candidate info Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="infoModal<%= applicant._id%>" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Candidate Info</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="mb-2 row">
              <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Candidate Name:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <p class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
                  <%=applicant.candidateName %>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 row">
              <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Candidate Email:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <p class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
                  <%= applicant.candidateEmail %>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 row">
              <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Candidate Mobile:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <p class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
                  <%= applicant.candidateMobile %>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 row">
              <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Candidate Degree:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <p class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
                  <%= applicant.candidateDegree %>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 row">
              <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Degree Percentage:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <p class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
                  <%= applicant.candidateDegreePercent %>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 row">
              <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Year Of Passing:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <p class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
                  <%= applicant.candidateYearOfPass %>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 row">
              <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Work Experience:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <p class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
                  <%= applicant.candidateExperience %>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 row">
              <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Skill:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <p class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
                  <%= applicant.candidateSkills %>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 row">
              <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Current Location:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <p class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
                  <%= applicant.candidateLocation %>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 row">
              <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Applied At:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <p class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
                  <%= applicant.appliedAt %>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Candidate info close -->
    <% }) %>
</ul>
```

In this image you will see that li tag loop with info button I want to open modal on that info click:

[image: img]

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: You need to put `MODAL` element outside of `UL` element because of when you click on info then `UL` element will hide so inside `UL` element `Modal` will also hide.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `MODAL` element outside of `UL` element because of when you click on **Info** button then `UL` element will hide so
inside `UL element`, `Modal element` will also hide.
 So simply its means when `parent element` hide then `child element` will automatically hide.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
        User Listing
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
        <% item.jobApplications.forEach((applicant)=>{ %>
            <li class="border border-dark">
                <!-- <a href="#infoModal<%= applicant._id %>" class="infobtn badge rounded-pill bg-info text-dark" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#infoModal<%= applicant._id %>">info</a> -->
                <button class="infobtn badge rounded-pill bg-info text-dark" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                    data-bs-target="#infoModal_1">info</button>
                <span class="small-bold">Name:</span>
                <span class="small">
                    <%=applicant.candidateName %>
                </span>
    
                <span class="small-bold">Percentage:</span></td>
                <span class="small">
                    <%=applicant.candidateDegreePercent %> %
                </span>
            </li>
        <% }) %>
    </ul>
    <!-- Candidate info Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="infoModal_1" tabindex="-1"
        aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Candidate Info</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="mb-2 row">
                        <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Candidate Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <p class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
                                <%=applicant.candidateName %>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Candidate Email:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <p class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
                                <%= applicant.candidateEmail %>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Candidate Mobile:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <p class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
                                <%= applicant.candidateMobile %>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Candidate Degree:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <p class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
                                <%= applicant.candidateDegree %>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Degree Percentage:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <p class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
                                <%= applicant.candidateDegreePercent %>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Year Of Passing:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <p class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
                                <%= applicant.candidateYearOfPass %>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Work Experience:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <p class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
                                <%= applicant.candidateExperience %>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Skill:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <p class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
                                <%= applicant.candidateSkills %>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Current Location:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <p class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
                                <%= applicant.candidateLocation %>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Applied At:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <p class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
                                <%= applicant.appliedAt %>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Candidate info close -->
</div>
```

Comment: You are right!, But Its not possible to add that modal outside UL or Loop because I am using dynamic modal for dynamic li which having unique ids in info name and modal name.

Comment: Yes, I know you are creating dynamic modal with loop so you can also create one more loop for modal as respectively of listing. then your listing info button id and modal id will same and then fire you modal for render.

Comment: Or Has one more trick to stop close `dropdown` on click `info` button then your problem will solve and when click outside of `dropdown` then close.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option would be to use a bit of JS here. Putting the modal inside of ul will be an issue (the one currently you are having), and having a different loop for modals (as another answer suggested) will also be an issue because it'll fill the DOM with too many elements which will slow the page down.

My advice will be to put the details you need in the modal as a data tag on the button (you click to open the modal). Then instead of opening the modal automatically on click, make it manual.

1. Add appropriate id to each part of the modal you want to fill.
2. Click the button.
3. In the event listener for the button, fetch the data from its data attributes and pass it onto the modal elements (from step 1).
4. Open the modal.

This way, your modal will be filled with dynamic data, and also won't need to be added more than once in your page.